# Split string into different columns of a particular maximum length in athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I want to split this string into different columns of maximum length of 40 while keeping the full words.

'Sheetla maata mandir road West Delhi Delhi'

The resulting columns should be

Col 1 : Sheetla maata mandir road West Delhi

Col 2: Delhi

Comment: What happens with an input of length 130?  Do you expect 4 columns in this case?

Comment: in case of string of length 130, yes.

Comment: Then you will need dynamic SQL to handle your requirement.  A fixed/static query cannot have a variable number of columns.